In Word VBA, set visible endnote text to hyperlink URL
I'm an experienced programmer, but not very familiar with VBA.
I'm trying to convert each hyperlinked text in a document to become an endnote, with the original text left in the document, and the endnote showing the URL, as plain text.
The VBA code at the end of this forum post gets me almost there, but the generated footnote shows the original linked text, rather the URL which is what I need. The problem line is the Rng.Endnotes(1).Range.FormattedText line:
Sub HLnk2FtNt()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim h As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For h = .Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Hyperlinks(h)
      Set Rng = .Range
      With Rng
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Endnotes.Add Rng
        .End = .End + 1
      End With
      Rng.Endnotes(1).Range.FormattedText = .Range.Hyperlinks(1).Address
      .Range.Fields.Unlink
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

This is failing with a Type mismatch error at .Address.
What should that reference be instead?

Think I've more-or-less cracked it - though perhaps there is a better way?
Sub HLnk2FtNt()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim h As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For h = .Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Hyperlinks(h)
      Set Rng = .Range
      With Rng
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Endnotes.Add Rng
        .End = .End + 1
      End With
      Rng.Endnotes(1).Range.FormattedText = .Range.FormattedText
      .Range.Text = .TextToDisplay
      With Rng.Endnotes(1).Range.Hyperlinks(1)
       .TextToDisplay = .Address
      End With
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

by merging in concepts in this answer.

You might notice both the original code from MSOfficeForums and the code you linked to from here were written by the same person - me!

@macropod - Ah yes, hadn't spotted that - thanks :) If you want to post a full solution as an answer, ideally better than whatever I cobbled together, please do, and I can accept it.

I take it you want to convert the hyperlink in the body to plain text. For that you could replace .Range.Text = .TextToDisplay with .Range.Fields(1).Unlink, which is probably a bit more efficient, but it's unlikely to matter unless you have masses of hyperlinks to process.
